# How can I update mysql database through Azure Data Factory when new rows are added in excel sheet?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have this excel sheet in my sharepoint. So, I connect to my excel sheet and then perform some ETL. This data is passed to a mysql database.

Now, suppose, I add new rows to my excel sheet. How can I tell Azure Data factory to only perform ETL on the new rows and add those to my mysql database.

So, I don't want to run the ETL process over all the rows again but only on the new rows.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a watermark column in your MS Excel file and then using the range Property.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-overview
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/solution-template-delta-copy-with-control-table

Sharepoint is not listed as a connector, but HTTP. You could use REST API calls to access the data in the MS
Excel.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-excel

Or you copy the file and the implement a filter logic in your ETL processing
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sharepoint-online-list#copy-file-from-sharepoint-online